# Using mod_rewrite on Ubuntu 14.04 to hide port and folders

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, domain, url

I have an AWS EC2 instance and I'm trying to point two different URLs to that same instance.

I am using NGINX (port 80) for a Ruby server and APACHE2 (port 8080) for a WordPress server.

I configured NGINX so that when a request for "blog.example.com", I redirect it to example.com:8080/html/wordpress/ as follows:

```
server{
   listen 80;
   server_name blog.example.com;

   location{
      proxy_pass http://example.com:8080/html/wordpress/;
   }
}
```

Accessing blog.example.com works fine for the homepage. However, when I try to, for example, log in, the URL I get is something like http://example.com:8080/html/wordpress/wp-login.php

What I'm trying to achieve is turn that URL into something like blog.example.com/wp-login.php or blog.example.com/login

I tried using mod_rewrite on the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file but I had no success.

000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName example.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule example.com:8080/html/wordpress/(.*)$  blog.example.com/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do to solve this? Is there a better way around this than rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Wordpress generate URLs that don't include port numbers. Web servers cannot do this task, since they cannot understand the HTML code well enough to reliably convert the URLs.

Comment: And how would you suggest I do that? I've never worked with Wordpress before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @fmlopes read wordpress docs, of course